# HTAccess Rewrite Based on Webpage Name?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

I have a list of items on a web-page of the form :

- `www.mydomain.com/item1-EUR.html`
- `www.mydomain.com/item1-GBP.html`
- `www.mydomain.com/item2-EUR.html`
- `www.mydomain.com/item2-GBP.html`

Is it possible to access the subsequent web-page file in :

`/myitems/eur/item1-EUR.html`, or `/myitems/gbp/item1-GBP.html`

I'm trying to show that the items web-pages are located in the root directory, but without cluttering up the root area.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules (preferably above any rules you may already have) in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-EUR\.html$ /myitems/eur/$1-EUR.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-GBP\.html$ /myitems/gbp/$1-GBP.html [L]
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the quick reply.

Is there a method to rewrite to the original base filename?

    RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-EUR\.html$ /myitems/eur/$1 [L]

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @user1000750 Yeah, I meant to use backreferences there, forgot to change them when I copied/pasted

Comment: Ah brilliant, I'm just now getting 404 errors "/item1-TEST.html" not found:( Thanks, Alan.

Comment: @user1000750 arbitrary "EUR" and "GBP" isn't going to be possible without initializing a rewrite map in you server/vhost config, in order to make the lowercase "eur" and "gbp", etc.

Comment: Hi again, is there anyway I can make it work with the current web-page names ad just a subdirectory containing all items in all currencies? Thank you so much again :)